# How can I reduce my input column width on Devise using Bootstrap Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I am a new coder and using Devise sign up authentication gem on RAILS. I am trying to customize the input columns for the sign up form. I would like to shorten the column width as they look too wide on the page.(from left to right)

See image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlOIT.png)

What can I add to my code to achieve this please.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your form into some container, that doesn't span all available width. Read about [Bootstrap's grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Bootstrap uses 12-column grid, so, if you, for example, want your form to take `1/3` of your page width, you need to wrap it into a `<div class="col-md-4"></div>` (since `12 / 3 = 4`).

Sure, I believe something like this should work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNRxGd

Comment: Alexey, really appreciate your help. Would you be kind enough to show me how this might look visually as a piece of code based on my code above.

Comment: Alexey this is inspiring to see this work on my page. I am super grateful for you taking the time out of your sunday to help. one little query. If you see the image of my page (just posted with an update with your fix). How do I get the sign in link to render below the Button.

Comment: @ChrisDormani Could you share your current html code (update your question with it)?

Comment: the code is your code exactly with a small piece at the end rendering.<label for="passwordconfirm">Password confirmation</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
</div>

<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

Comment: Well, try to put devise links into the `<div class="col-md-4">`

Comment: I will repost a new question as I believe that is best practise if the question has been answered. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335652/how-can-i-get-the-sign-in-link-to-render-below-the-sign-up-button-using-bootstra/33335932#33335932

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<h2>Signup</h2>

<form class="form-signup">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="passwordconfirm">Password confirmation</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of two different ways you could do this: one just limits the size (width) of the form itself and the other uses `columns` (which you can adjust in many ways, this is just one.)

See [Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) and [Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Working examples below.

```css
.form-signup {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-signup .form-signup-heading {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form-signup .form-control {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-signup-heading text-center">
    <h2>Sign up if you don't have an account:</h2>

  </div>
  <form class="form-signup">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="passwordconfirm">Password confirmation</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
</div>
<hr>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2 class="text-center">Sign up if you don't have an account:</h2>

    <form class="form-signup2">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="passwordconfirm">Password confirmation</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: - this is kind of you. Is example 2 implemented in the registrations/new.html.erb folder

Comment: And your example 1. The short piece of code. Is that put below my code above in the new.html.erb folder  of registrations prior to END

Comment: Yes, in new.html.erb and you need to create a div like`<div class="form-signup">` that starts before the form_for and after end or your links depending on how your views are setup.

Comment: how do you mean exactly. Should I just cut and paste this whole tranche and bump it into new.html.erb

Comment: You can leave `<div class="form-signup">` there but I would move it above `form_for` and you put the CSS in your stylesheets directory, not directly on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap, especially v4 and above, spans form fields. you need to place your code in a container, usually a column so that it does not fill the whole page.
Examples and recommendations from @Chris Dormani and @Alexei Shein are correct.