# How can I get the Sign in link to render below the Sign up Button using Bootstrap for Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I am a new coder using Rails. I am configuring the Devise signup page using Bootstrap.

As per the image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb2Kq.png)

What can I do to my code to get the "Sign in" link relocated to sit below the "Sign Up' Button to make it look aesthetically better.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<h2>Signup</h2>

 <form class="form-signup">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="passwordconfirm">Password confirmation</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">SignUp</button>
</form>
</div>
<% end %>


<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the SignUp inside  it will be in new row.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button></div>
```

Have a look @ the code: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13646/embedded/result/

Comment: Thank you very much. Will try this out

Comment: Just to clarify. I am not wanting a new button for signin. Just a small link underneath the button left aligned.

Comment: Does your code achieve this based on my image description. Thanks

Comment: Yes. check the link provided https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13646/embedded/result/ for output and for code you can have a look @ https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13646/

Comment: oh you just need a link not a button. then just remove the button and place the link inside that. changed the code for you: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13647/ you need to replace <a> tag with your code. <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

Comment: no. I want the sign in link to be below the Signup button.

Comment: your code produces an error. Can you look at my code and input the correct change to achieve this please

Comment: Change your code from <%= render "devise/shared/links" %> to <div class="form-group"><%= render "devise/shared/links" %></div>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of what you're trying to do. Enclose the whole form and the login link in `<div class="form-signup"></div>`.

[image]

**Keep in mind this example is just to show you the structure, don't copy and paste in into your application.

```
 <div class="form-signup-heading text-center">
    <h2>Sign up if you don't have an account:</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="form-signup">

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <% if @minimum_password_length %>
        <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
        <% end %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

  </div>
```

Comment: You're welcome and if you're questions get answered on SO, don't forget to mark them as answered so they're removed from the queue and others will benefit from them then.

Comment: Noted will try this out and revert

Comment: I am looking for put the Sign in link below the Sign Up button. I am not wanting a dedicated button for Sign in on this page Vanburen. What can I do to my existing code.  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %> puts the link away across the page as per the image description. thanks